# How can I create a heat map based values (not frequencies)?

Tags: python, google-maps, data-visualization, heatmap

I am doing a project which is creating a heat map based on a set of data that includes 4 things: timestamp, longitude, latitude, one specific value.

I use [heatmap.py](http://jjguy.com/heatmap/) to read the data and create a KML file and png file, and then put them on google maps. However, this creates a heatmap based on the "hits", but I want to base the map intensity on the specific value, not the frequency of occurrence of that value. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389623/generating-a-kml-heatmap-from-given-data-set-of-lat-lon-density

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this question has your answer: [Generating a KML heatmap from given data set of [lat, lon, density]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389623/generating-a-kml-heatmap-from-given-data-set-of-lat-lon-density)

And the answer is by [J.J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234652/j-j), the creator of heatmap.py. As of 2010, he was planning to get around to implementing that functionality in heatmap.py, but it seems he hasn't gotten around to it yet. But in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389623/generating-a-kml-heatmap-from-given-data-set-of-lat-lon-density/2658603#2658603) he gives some hints on how to code it yourself . . .

Comment: Thanks, I will read that topic later. Anyway, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack, but if your values can be scaled to smallish integers, you could just create copies of your points. That is, if you have points `[a,b,c]` with values `[2,1,4]`, you could make a heat map of `[a,a,b,c,c,c,c]`.

Comment: I also think about this. However, the range of the value is 3xx to 1xxx…